# Is ncurses a good choice to implement a command history in a C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, command, history, ncurses

I am a student and I'm taking a course where my project is to write a server using unix sockets, threads or epoll, and so forth.

However, as the client takes his input from the user, I wanted to go an extra mile and give it some sort of memory for the commands he has given in the past; like the shell or gdb has.

I have no idea how to do this, can you guys help me? I put ncurses in the title because I suspect I'm supposed to use it, but I don't know how, I never used ncurses before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GNU readline library](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/) provides this functionality.